# Magento Single product post CSS not working

Tags: magento-1.9

this is the URL http://rvpartscenter.rv-solutions.com/appliances-accessories/olympian-wave-8-catalytic-rv-heater.html

For some reason, style is not working. this is a default installation of Magento.

Pls help me understand why  it is happening. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oh... I got it now. I have to set the design for each product.

Dashboard > Catalog > Design >
Set Custom Design   and Page Layout.